# What observable is visualized in lattice QCD visualizations?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, lattice-model, visualization

I have seen a couple of visualizations of lattice QCD, for instance the [images by Derek Leinweber](http://www.physics.adelaide.edu.au/theory/staff/leinweber/VisualQCD/QCDvacuum/). Using my own data I would like to make similar visualizations. I am just not sure what I actually see on this image.

The quantity visualized must be a gauge invariant observable. So just using the links $U_{\mu\nu}$ is not sensible as those can be gauged differently. Besides they are unitary matrices, one would have to reduce that to some scalar value in order to visualize. The real part of the trace of the plaquette would be possible. But that is only defined on the surfaces of the hypercubic lattice. This lattice is not a simple cubic lattice any more. A simple 3D density plot would not suffice, one would have to map several surfaces into one lattice point or so.

On one [Austrian university page](http://ati.tuwien.ac.at/research_areas/nuclear_and_particle_physics/research/fundamental_interactions/lattice_qcd/EN/) such an image is posted saying:

> Action density of the QCD vacuum

The action should be an observable quantity and it also should be real. This is good for visualization and basically the plaquette plus the fermions. I am just not sure how the mapping goes then. The plaquettes are defined on the cube surfaces, the fermions in the action are defined on either side of a link.

- How does one map the action contributions defined on hybercubic surfaces and hypercubic edges to a hypercubic lattice?
- Does one use appropriately positioned metaballs instead and does not have to deal with this?

Comment: Why don't you take a look at the paper that Leinweber references on his page? In case you missed it, this is the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/0004025

Comment: Indeed I missed the paper. However I only know now that it shows the action density or the topological charge (I am familiar with that right now). But I do not see how the mapping has been done. The only technicality I found is “isosurface” but it does not say on which positions the action density is to be understood. Perhaps it does not really matter too much since there is interpolation used anyway. I'd still be interested in the details.

Comment: I don't know anything more about this than you, so I hope someone else can answer your questions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is plotted is iso-contours of the euclidean action density ${\rm Tr}[E^2+B^2]$ and topological charge density ${\rm Tr}[E\cdot B]$, where $E$ and $B$ can be defined using the plaquette $U_{\mu\nu}(n)$ in the usual way ($E_i^a\sim {\rm Tr}([U_{0i}-1]\lambda^a)$ etc). The issues is not so much having to interpolate the observables from a discrete lattice (standard visualization software has routines to do that), but the need to filter the bare lattice fields. Lattice gauge fields are very rough, and if you tried to plot them you would not see anything but noise. What is done in these plots is that the gauge fields were smoothed using some algorithm like cooling or gradient flow. The cooling algorithm is very simple: Use the standard Metropolis method, but only accept updates that lower the action. This will drive the gauge fields towards the closest semi-classical configuration, which you can think of as some kind of multi-instanton configuration.

Comment: Okay, that sounds very sensible. I still wonder how the interpolation of $P_{\mu\nu}(n)$ onto a simple cubic grid is done. Just taking $\sum_{\mu \neq \nu} P_{\mu\nu}(n)$ (as I currently do) seems a little incorrect as the plaquette is centered around $n + \mu/2 + \nu/2$ really. So just summing all plaquettes which have the bottom right corner at $n$ does not seem symmetric.

Comment: The six plaquettes that contribute to $E^2+B^2$ are faces of the same hypercube, so it is reasonable to use the center of this cube.